# Changing placeholder text in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I'm trying to change the placeholder text of my chatroom app's textfield every time that the user goes onto the page.

Is there a simple code to access into the placeholder text from inside my ViewController.m file (instead of just changing it from the storyboard drawing board area?)

basically I have a dictionary of values and based on arbitrary conditions I want the placeholder text in the text field to change whenever the user refreshes the tableview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean

```
myTextField.placeholder = @"your placeholder text";
```